# How can I use the same console window with the /WAIT capability for each process in my BAT-file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Windows 7 x64.

In my `BAT`-file I need wait the ending of the each process. I use such syntax:

```
start /WAIT "Title 1" app1.exe
start /WAIT "Title 2" app1.exe
...
start /WAIT "Title n" appn.exe
```

But at this case ewery program opens own console-window (while it works). I want all apps to use the same console window, where my `BAT`-file was called. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the help on Start (`start /?`) you'll see you can use `/b` switch to use same window. Start's help also contains the description of starting programs with or without using `start`.

The only reasons you would use start rather than calling the program direct is to set window title or to have EXPLORER look up the program's path from it's `App Paths` registry key (`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`), typically console programs don't register themselves here.

Comment: From Help `When executing an application that is a 32-bit GUI application, CMD.EXE
    does not wait for the application to terminate before returning to
    the command prompt.  This new behavior does NOT occur if executing
    within a command script.
`

Comment: cmd is an annoying beast. It turns out that while if `CreateProcess` fails it will call `ShellExecuteEx` without requiring `start`, it will only do so for files it has *already* found by searching `PATH`, whereas `start` will always call `ShellExecuteEx` to consult the `App Paths` key. But please back off on the "only reasons" language; there are lots of other reasons to use `start` such as setting process working directory, priority, CPU affinity, or window state. Also, Explorer is not involved here; `shell32!ShellExecuteExW` is run by cmd.exe.

Comment: I call the Windows Shell Explorer so people know what I'm talking about, and I'm referring to the Start - Run dialog.

Comment: When it talks about *New Behaviour* it's referring to NT4's CMD vs the new Windows 2000's CMD. IBM wrote CMD for OS/2, MS put it in NT, but updated it for Win2000.

Comment: Where are you referring to the start run dialog? As in Explorer's dialog that's opened by Win+R?  Anyway, saying Explorer is involved would require interprocess communication between cmd.exe and explorer.exe (e.g. a COM call over LPC/RPC), but really it's shell32.dll loaded in cmd.exe that does all the work.

Comment: Shell32 does all the work anyway. Nonetheless people know the Windows Shell by it's program name Explorer.exe, that prior to XP, was a program that provided basically a frame for Windows Explorer AND Internet Explorer (and also the taskbar and Start menu).